# Can my device be tracked if I've turned off Find my iPhone and restored it?

Tags: ios, icloud, find-my-iphone

I've turned off Find my iPhone and reset all the iCloud email, iMessage, etc. Once I pressed Reset, my iPhone 5 rebooted and its on. I need to choose a language and country. That means the iPhone is as new and I'm wondering if my mom can track me now?

Answer (score 1):

If you turn off find my iphone, and log out of iCloud, then you can't be tracked via that method.  Of course, your Mom would need your Apple ID in order to do that anyway, and as such if she can simply log into iCloud.com with your ID she will be able to see that the tracking has been turned off.  Also log out of Find my Friends if you use that.

However, on a more personal note, where are you going that you need to keep a secret ;)